# How to Connect a Web App to Hunchentoot

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I am writing a web app that would require the hunchentoot web server. I have almost no working knowledge of hunchentoot, or any web server for that matter, and I am wondering how my app written in Common Lisp would serve pages to a web client. I have seen some excellent examples (e.g. [Hunchentoot Primer](http://www.newartisans.com/blog_files/hunchentoot.primer.php), Lisp for the Web) esp. the one listed on the Hunchentoot page. Do you know where I can find more of such examples?
Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you find lacking in the examples? If you don't say, chances are you'll get more links to examples that lack the same thing.

Comment: Well, I'd like to see more clearly how to connect the rest of the application's code to hunchentoot; just how the app should talk to hunchentoot.

Comment: The link is dead, long live the new link: http://newartisans.com/2007/11/a-quick-hunchentoot-primer/

Answer (score 8):

> I am wondering how my app written in Common Lisp would serve pages to a web client.

Hunchentoot serves all things that are in its `*dispatch-table*`, which is just a list of dispatch handlers.

The simplest thing to do is to serve a static file.  One typical example would be a CSS file:

```
(push (create-static-file-dispatcher-and-handler "/example.css"
                                                 "example.css")
      *dispatch-table*)
```

For a web application, you would most likely want to dynamically create a web page.  You do this by defining a function that returns the page as a string (e.g. with CL-WHO), then creating a handler for this function:

```
(defun foo ()
  (with-html-output-to-string ; ...
  ))

(push (create-prefix-dispatcher "/foo.html" 'foo)
      *dispatch-table*)
```

You can eliminate a lot of boilerplate through macros, by the way:

```
(defmacro standard-page ((title) &body body)
  `(with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output* nil :prologue t :indent t)
     (:html :xmlns "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          :xml\:lang "de"
          :lang "de"
          (:head 
           (:meta :http-equiv "Content-Type" 
                      :content "text/html;charset=utf-8")
           (:title ,title)
               (:link :type "text/css" 
              :rel "stylesheet"
              :href "/example.css"))
              (:body
               ,@body))))

(defmacro defpage (name (title) &body body)
  `(progn
     (defmethod ,name ()
       (standard-page (,title)
         ,@body))
     (push (create-prefix-dispatcher ,(format nil "/~(~a~).html" name) ',name)
           *dispatch-table*)))
```

The examples you have found should be sufficient to get you started, and if you run into problems, read the manual, then ask concrete questions.

Comment: I cannot serve a static html linked to a css file by using `create-static-file-dispatcher-and-handler` for html file. What should i do?

Comment: @FSC: It seems that you have a new question.  Post it as such, and provide the necessary context, please.

Answer (score 2):

`define-easy-handler` registers the handler you are defining automatically in a global variable which gets checked when a HTTP request arrives (the variable is called `*easy-handler-alist*`). So it's being taken care of automatically. Do you want to use a handler of a different form than the one defined in the tutorial?

I think there is an example using Hunchentoot in the Elephant distribution ([Elephant](http://common-lisp.net/project/elephant/index.html) being a Persistent Object Database for Common Lisp.)